# Removing extra spaces in print()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to show a progress like

```
[500/5000] [1000/5000] [1500/5000] ...
```

With the following print line

```
print("[",str(c),"/",str(len(my_list)),"] ", end='')
```

I see extra spaces like `[ 1000 / 55707 ] [ 2000 / 55707 ]`. I also tried

```
print('[{}'.format(c),"/",'{}]'.format(len(my_list))," ", end='')
```

But the output is `[1000 / 55707]  [2000 / 55707]`.

How can I I fix that?

Comment: This doesn't really answers your question but the `tqdm` implement a nice progress bar if you want to use it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call print() with several arguments, they are separated by default by a space. You should call :

```
print("[",str(c),"/",str(len(my_list)),"] ", end='', sep='')
```

But the best and most modern way of doing is using f-strings :

```
print(f"[{c}/{len(my_list)}] ", end='')
```